# Opening editor and creating Hello World -app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I downloaded Xcode 7.2 and I have tried to create a simple Hello World -iOS app. I just can't figure it out how to open the correct file and write that simple code for view. in Youtube vids it happens easily but... ...I don't know.

When I open the Assistant Editor it only shows me a source of 'UIViewController.h', this is not the file I'm looking for(?) (see image below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the Objective-C code you're seeing, just understand that you're using Cocoa and Cocoa was written in Objective-C so, there's a lot of bridging between Swift & Objective-C going on behind the scenes.

Although Xcode usually will open the right file for you when you click the Assistant Editor, it doesn't always so don't assume that you're looking at the correct file because Xcode presented it to you. Check first.

Here's what you have to do to find out which code file you're working in.

- click on your view in your Main.storyboard.
- look at which class you are using in your identity inspector on the right. In this case, it's ViewController.
- Then in your project navigator on your left, you'll find your file which, generally, has the same name as your class.
- Just add some code to your `viewDidLoad` in your ViewController.swift

[image]

If this is your first time working with Xcode, just do this for your first experiment. Add a print statement to your viewDidLoad like this:

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Hello World")
}
```

Build and run and your console should pop up.

Comment: I created a new project and well... ...everything seems to work. (I tried ur solution but it did't work - idk why)

Comment: @user2468160 Judging by the picture you've included, it looks like you may have deleted some views from Main.storybaord correct?

Comment: That could be the reason...

Comment: @user2468160 Well, if you look over my answer closely I'm showing you something rather useful that you'll need to know from now on with Xcode. If you delete views from your storyboard and add new ones, you'll need to associate a code file in your Identity Inspector in order for the assistant editor to know about the file.